# LocationInformation in LoggingEvent in CustomAppendar

Tags: log4net, log4net-appender, log4net-configuration, log4net-filter

I have written custon Appendar and override Append method. I am getting LoggingEvent in that method but when I looked at LocationInformation it is empty it shows only "?" in following properties.

```
protected override void Append(log4net.Core.LoggingEvent loggingEvent)
{

ClassName = loggingEvent.LocationInformation.ClassName /*contains "?"*/,
MethodName = loggingEvent.LocationInformation.MethodName /*contains "?"*/,
FileName = loggingEvent.LocationInformation.FileName /*contains "?"*/,
FullInfo = loggingEvent.LocationInformation.FullInfo /*contains "?"*/,

}
```

What I am doing wrong ?

Thanks

Comment: Do you use a wrapper for log4net?

Comment: No I do not use Wrapper for Logger. I am trying to get loggingEvent in Appendar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try adding following line in the constructor of your custome appender:

```
Fix = FixFlags.All;
```

Comment: Probably because i am running on .Net Core 3

Answer (score 0):

Set the Fix Property on the LoggingEvent in the Append-Method:

```
protected override void Append(LoggingEvent loggingEvent)
{
     loggingEvent.Fix = FixFlags.All;

     var className = loggingEvent.LocationInformation.ClassName;
     // ... 
}
```